# Problema com Fuction js

Tags: javascript

Dentro da function `montarTr` aparece o erro:

> Cannot read property 'conta' of undefined at montarTr

```js
var botao = document.querySelector("#addConta");
botao.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // BUSCANDO O CONTEUDO DENTRO DO FORMS
  var form = document.querySelector("#formAdd");

  var trgastos = getValores(form);

  // CRIANDOO TR
  var createTr = montarTr(trgastos)

  // CRIANDO TD DENTRO DA TR


  // TODO O CONTEUDO DENTRO DA TR PASSA PARA TB 
  var tabela = document.querySelector("#table")

  tabela.appendChild(createTr);
});

function getValores(form) {
  var trgastos = {
    conta: form.conta.value,
    valor: form.valor.value,
    info: form.info.value,
    total: ""
  }

  return trgastos;
}

function montarTr(trgastos) {
  var createTr = document.createElement("tr");
  createTr.classList.add("trgastos");

  console.log(createTr);

  createTr.appendChild(montarTr(trgastos.conta, "info-conta"));
  createTr.appendChild(montarTr(trgastos.valor, "info-valor"));
  createTr.appendChild(montarTr(trgastos.info, "info"));
  createTr.appendChild(montarTr(trgastos.total, "info-total"));

  return createTr;

}

function montarTd(dado, classe) {
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.classList.add(classe);
  td.textContent = dado

  return td;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/materialize.css">


  <title>Controle de Gastos</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="responsive-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="tituloTb">
        <th>CONTA</th>
        <th>PREÇO</th>
        <th>INFO </th>
        <th>TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table">
      <tr id="trgastos">
        <td class="info-conta">Conta de luz</td>
        <td class="info-preco">R$:350,00</td>
        <td class="info">Mês 05</td>
        <td class="info-total">0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <section class="form">
    <div class="row">
      <form id="formAdd" class="col s12">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="novaConta" name="conta" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="novaConta" style="text-align: center;">Nova Conta</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="novoValor" name="valor" type="number" class="validate">
          <label for="novoValor" style="text-align: center;">Valor</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="novainfo" name="info" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="novainfo" style="text-align: center;">info</label>
      </div>
    </div>


    <button id="addConta" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
  </section>
  <!--
  <script src="/js/form.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/calculo.js"></script>
-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema que você tem está na função montarTr(), na qual foi criado um loop infinito.

Assim que você aperta o botão, a função montarTr é disparada e recebe o seguinte objeto

```
{
    conta: 1,
    valor: 2,
    info: 3,
    total: ""
}
```

A função será executada normalmente até a seguinte linha

```
createTr.appendChild(montarTr(trgastos.conta, "info-conta"));
```

Nessa linha, a função montarTr será chamada novamente, porém, dessa vez o valor passado para ela será 1, assim que essa execução for realizada e chegar nessa mesma linha, o próximo valor passado será a posição conta do **inteiro** 1, que é **undefined**, e na execução seguinte, um erro é disparado pois não é possível acessar uma propriedade de undefined.